Dual Criminality for weapons?
The various forms of defensive spray, like pepper spray, are illegal in the United Kingdom under the Firearms Act for civilians to carry.
In the Kingdom of Spain, certain pepper spray brands are legal for civilians to carry.
I was curious how an extradition would work, where the UK wants to prosecute someone for pepper spray, by extraditing them from Spain. The Dual Criminality requirement is met, since both countries have laws prohibiting firearms.
However, since pepper spray itself is legal in Spain, would the extradition be allowed?

Commenting as I have maxed out on pending edits, pepper spray is a weapons subject to general prohibition see section 5(1)(b)

I would expect that, even if both countries had English laws, there would be no extradition if the punishment is small enough.

@SJuan76 The punishment is over a year in each jurisdiction, so the punishment is big enough to enable an extradition.

Canada and most other jurisdictions internationally have opted to implement the double criminality principle through the conduct-based approach that asks whether the conduct in the foreign jurisdiction could amount to an offence under domestic law.
In the extradition proceedings for Wanzhou Meng, it was alleged that Huawei misled a U.S. bank about Huawei's connections with Iran. The bank was subject to the Iranian Transaction and Sanctions Regulations and a deferred prosecution agreement that required the bank to not provide financial assistance with certain connections to Iran (United States v Meng, 2020 BCSC 785).
Ms. Meng's alleged conduct would have amounted to fraud in the U.S.
But, the alleged misstatements would not have been material in Canada and would not amount to fraud:

The parties agree ... that ... financial institutions operating in Canada would not have been at risk of penalty for engaging in financial transactions or providing credit to companies doing business in Iran.

It would have been legal for Ms. Weng to submit the offending documents to a bank in Canada.
Nevertheless, the double criminality requirement was met.
The court rejected a fine parsing of the "conduct." It did not consider it at a "narrow" scope of the precise misstatement. This would "unduly isolate" the facts from the context of the fraud. Instead, the court took a broader view of the "conduct." The question was more properly whether materially false statements to a bank could constitute fraud in Canada.

So, whether double criminality is met in your circumstance will depend on the scope at which the court views the conduct.
If the conduct is conceived of as the possession of pepper spray specifically, then dual criminality will not be made out.
If instead the conduct is considered more broadly as the possession of a prohibited weapon, then dual criminality will be made out.

That is a fantastic answer. Looking at the last part of your answer, how would the conduct be determined as to whether it was possession of pepper spray, or possession of a prohibited weapon? As you explained, this makes a huge difference!

Extradition would not be allowed since this violates the principle of dual criminality. Pepper spray is not a firearm.

The law might be called the Firearm Act, but it also covers pepper spray and other noxious liquids.

Just since this is a very similar scenario, let me ask: what would happen if both countries have laws against having sex with minors, could Spain refuse to extradite someone because their age of consent is 13 unlike 16 in the UK? I know Spain recently changed from 13 to 16, this is just an example.

@user5623335 If they're under 13, it's illegal in both countries, so they should extradite. If they're between 13 and 15 it's legal in Spain, so they shouldn't extradite.

In Germany, it would be illegal to carry a pepper spray which has not been certified by the German authorities. So would Germany extradite people for carrying a pepper spray in the UK which has not been certified by the UK authorities?

@o.m. Probably, unless the severity of the punishment in Germany was much lighter than in the U.K.

@Barmar the analysis of extradition for minors may involve additional considerations not present for adults.

@ohwilleke I thought they were talking about extraditing the adult perpetrator, not the minor victim.

But if it's a minor-on-minor incident, then I agree that there are other considerations.

@user5623335: Then why did you say "laws prohibiting firearms" instead of "laws prohibiting pepper spray" in your question?

@user2357112 Sorry, bad wording on my part.

@Barmar and ohwilleke I am talking about an adult sleeping with someone that is like 13, 14, or 15 years old. Since Spain used to have the age of consent set at 13, could the offender avoid extradition, since their conduct would not be considered a crime in Spain?

@user5623335 I see. I misunderstood you. Ultimately, dual criminality is primarily an issue for diplomats to interpret, subject to potential checks by courts. I could see legitimate arguments either way.

@ohwilleke Taking a conduct approach on both the pepper spray and the age of consent examples above, the conduct would not amount to a crime in Spain. Shame that sometimes the law is not so clear cut.

@user5623335 If the law were clear cut it would put us lawyers out of business. In truth, there are so many possible permutations of things that could come up that legislators are ill-equipped to evaluate well without context to guide them that we have to put faith in people given the job of figuring it out to come up with good answers on a case by case basis.

@ohwilleke Please do not kill me for saying this, but I thought the whole point of a Civil Legal System in a developed country (or at least one which invests sufficiently into their legal system) would not have these ambiguities :-p. I always took Civil as more clear cut!

@user5623335 The civil law system is not more clear cut than the common law system, and probably, it is less clear cut, because common law precedents provide a greater gloss of guidance. But the ambiguities are similar and are very hard to reduce.
